# Left channel extraction / fade out on WAV file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, wav, web-audio-api

I get a WAV file from user upload (basically a file input) and have to do some manipulation with that:

1. Validate is it's a valid .wav file
2. If user uploaded a stereo file, extract a single channel (left)
3. Add w fade out at the end (50 last samples of the file)

My first thought was `hey, there's an api for that (web audio)`, so I did something similar to:

```
const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
const splitter = audioContext.createChannelSplitter(audioBuffer.numberOfChannels);
const gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.connect(splitter);

gainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(0, audioBuffer.duration);

splitter.connect(gainNode, 0);
```

Which in my thinking is taking the first channel out of the source and adding linear fade out (not really on last 50 samples, but that's not a point for now).

But...

How do I extract the output of that into a file? I know how to play manipulated sound frontend side, but am I able to turn it back into a file?

So at some point I assumed there's no way to do that, so I came up with a different solution, which uses low level file manipulation, that goes as follows:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  // const arrayBuffer = await toArrayBuffer(file);
  const audioBuffer = await decodeAudio(audioContext, arrayBuffer);

  const channels = 1;
  const duration = audioBuffer.duration;
  const rate = audioBuffer.sampleRate;
  const length = Math.ceil(duration * rate * channels * 2 + 44);
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(length);
  const view = new DataView(buffer);
  let position = 0;
  let offset = 0;

  const setUint16 = (data) => {
    view.setUint16(position, data, true);
    position += 2;
  };

  const setUint32 = (data) => {
    view.setUint32(position, data, true);
    position += 4;
  };

  setUint32(0x46464952); // RIFF
  setUint32(length - 8); // file length
  setUint32(0x45564157); // WAV

  setUint32(0x20746d66); // fmt
  setUint32(16); // data size
  setUint16(1); // PCM
  setUint16(channels);
  setUint32(rate);
  setUint32(rate * 16 * channels);
  setUint16(channels * 2);
  setUint16(16);

  setUint32(0x61746164); // "data"
  setUint32(length - position - 4);

  const leftChannel = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  let sample;

  console.log('left', leftChannel);
  console.log('length', length);
  while (position < length) {
    sample = leftChannel[offset];
    sample = sample < 0 ? sample * 0x8000 : sample * 0x7FFF;
    view.setInt16(position, sample, true);
    position += 2;
    offset++;
  }

  console.log('buffer', buffer);

  const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: file.type });
```

but seems it has a lot of flows, output is distorted / has different sample rate and so on...

My question then would be:

1. How do I extract a file out of a web audio api, if that's even possible? Cause that the best way to do that imho
2. If (1) is not possible, what am I doing wrong on the second approach?

Answer (score 1):

WebAudio has no way of saving audio to a file.  You can use [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) as one way, but I don't think that that's required to support WAV files.  Or you can do it by hand as you show above.  At a glance I don't see anything wrong with what you've done.  Might be helpful to look at what Chrome does to [save files](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/web_tests/webaudio/resources/audio-file-utils.js) in its test suite; it does basically what you do.